# Краткий вывод текста в Gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#

На веб форме имеется элемент Gridview один из столбцов которых является примечанием, при вводе в него даже не сильно длинного текста вид таблицы становится ужасным, можно каким нибудь образом сделать краткий текст, допустим 2-3 слова и "..." Или придумать что либо альтернативное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Можно, например, ячейкам в столбце "Примечание" присвоить определенный класс CSS, а в нем написать overflow: hidden. Тогда текст, который не влазит не будет отображаться. 2)Еще можно с jQuery поковыряться, к примеру, если слов больше двух, то заменить на первые два слова и на  многоточие,а весь текст записать в скрытые поля, что бы потом извлечь.
3) И еще как вариант, можно сделать это на сервере. С помощью шаблонов (Template), так же проверять на количество слов (или, если хотите, букв), если превышает в label писать, также первые два слова с многоточием и button рядом создать, по нажатию на который, показывать весь текст в ячейке. Как-то так.